# $\int\cosh^3(x)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

My attempt:

$\int\cosh^3(x)dx = \int\cosh(x)(1+sinh^2(x))^2dx$

$let\ u=sinh(x)$

$du=cosh(x)dx$

$\int u^4 + 2u^2 + 1\ du = \frac 15u^5+\frac23u^3+u = \frac 15sinh^5x + \frac 23 sinh^3(x)+sinh(x)+C$

Correct answer:

$sinh(x)+\frac 13 sinh^3(x) + C$

Comment: Why did you _square_ the $ \ 1 \ + \ \sinh^2 x \ $ factor?

Comment: Your mistake is in the first line (though the methodology is correct). You have an extra square in the expression. $$\cosh^3(x) = \cosh(x)\cosh^2(x) = \cosh(x)(1+\sinh^2(x)).$$

Comment: oh i see it now, thanks guys

Comment: You have $\cosh^3(x)=\cosh(x)(1+\sinh(x)^2)$, so you should get $\int (1+u^2) du$ after substitution.

Comment: @Kurumi You're welcome! Just make that slight change and follow the logic you have above and you'll get the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were wrong in your very first step \begin{align*}\cosh^3x&=\cosh x\cdot \cosh^2 x\\&=\cosh x\cdot (1+\sinh^2 x)\end{align*} Not $\cosh x\cdot (1+\sinh^2x)^\color{red}2$.

Answer (score 0):

Use $\cosh(x) = \dfrac{1}{2}(e^{-x}+e^x)$, the integrate is

$$\dfrac{1}{24}(-e^{-3x}-9e^{-x}+9e^x+e^{3x})+constant=\dfrac{3}{4}\sinh(x)+\dfrac{1}{12}\sinh(3x)+constant$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice, 
$$\int \cosh^3 x\ dx=\int \cosh x(1+\sinh^2 x)\ dx$$
$$=\int \cosh x\ dx+\int \sinh^2 x\cosh x\ dx$$
let $\sinh x=u\implies \cosh x\ dx=du$
$$=\int \cosh x dx+\int u^2\ du$$
$$=\sinh x+\frac{u^3}{3}+C$$
$$=\sinh x+\frac{1}{3}\sinh^3 x+C$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Just as with trigonometric functions, use multiple angle formulas $$\cosh(3x)=4\cosh^3(x)-3\cosh(x)$$So $$\cosh^3(x)=\frac 14 \cosh(3x)+\frac 34 \cosh(x)$$ $$\int \cosh^3(x)\,dx=\frac 14 \int\cosh(3x)\,dx+\frac 34\int \cosh(x)\,dx$$ $$\int \cosh^3(x)\,dx=\frac 1{12} \sinh(3x)\, dx+\frac 34 \sinh(x)\,dx$$